# SQL Sandbox Environment

Tags: mysql, sql, sandbox

Does anyone know of a sandbox I can use to practise and learn SQL? I downloaded MYSQL Workbench 6.0 and I cant seem to work out where or how I just practise SQL querying. If anyone has another environment they can recommend I would really appreciate it.
Thank you everyone who responds in advance.
Damian

Comment: You can use sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: SqlFiddle does not work in slightly-advanced queries.

Comment: There is a very good one at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc